# Remove a line from a csv file bash, sed, bash

Tags: bash, command-line, sed

I'm looking for a way to remove lines within multiple csv files, in bash using sed, awk or anything appropriate  where the file ends in 0.

So there are multiple csv files, their format is:

```
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6
EXAMPLEbar,30,10
EXAMPLElong,60,0
EXAMPLEcon,120,6
EXAMPLEdev,60,0
EXAMPLErandom,30,6
```

So the file will be amended to:

```
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6
EXAMPLEbar,30,10
EXAMPLEcon,120,6
EXAMPLErandom,30,6
```

A problem which I can see arising is distinguishing between double digits that end in zero and 0 itself.

So any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at my FOSS project http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ which is intended to do exactly this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using your file, something like this?

```
$ sed '/,0$/d' test.txt 
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6 
EXAMPLEbar,30,10 
EXAMPLEcon,120,6 
EXAMPLErandom,30,6
```

Comment: Exactly, thanks alot, for some reason, I had imagined it would me more complex that that.

Answer (score 5):

For this particular problem, `sed` is perfect, as the others have pointed out. However, `awk` is more flexible, i.e. you can filter on an arbitrary column:

```
awk -F, '$3!=0' test.csv
```

This will print the entire line is column 3 is not 0.

Answer (score 2):

use sed to only remove lines ending with ",0":

```
   sed  '/,0$/d'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use awk,

```
$ awk -F"," '$NF!=0' file
EXAMPLEfoo,60,6
EXAMPLEbar,30,10
EXAMPLEcon,120,6
EXAMPLErandom,30,6
```

this just says check the last field for `0` and don't print if its found.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/,[ \t]*0$/d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to sed, but there is an egrep (or: grep -e) -solution too:

```
egrep -v ",0$" example.csv
```